# Partial derivative of nabla operation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, laplace-transform, laplacian

Given that
$$\nabla^2f = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x'^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y'^2}$$

$$ x = x' \cos \theta - y'\sin \theta   \\
y = x' \sin \theta + y'\cos \theta
 $$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x'} $$

I obtain and understand how to get the following
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \sin \theta $$

But I don't understand how the following is obtained? i.e. how the $\sinθ\cosθ$ terms.

$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x'^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\cos^2\theta+ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})\sin\theta\cos\theta + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})\cos\theta\sin\theta +  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\sin^2\theta $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that
$$
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} =  \cos\theta  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \sin\theta  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.
$$
Note that you can rewrite this as 
$$ 
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} =  \left(\cos\theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sin\theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) f.
$$
Therefore you have found the derivative w.r.t. $x'$ in terms of the derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, namely 
$$ 
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} =  \cos\theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sin\theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
$$
Therefore
$$
 \begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x'^2}   
      &=\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} \\
    &= \left(\cos\theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sin\theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left( \cos\theta  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \sin\theta  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)  \\
  &= \cos^2\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \sin \theta\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \cos \theta \sin\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \sin^2\theta \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.
 \end{align*}
$$

Comment: How $$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x'^2}   
      =\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$$ ?? Would you mind explaining?

Comment: This is the definition of a second derivative: it is the derivative of the function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$ with respect to $x'$.

Comment: I don't think I've shown that $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} =  \cos\theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sin\theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}. $$ I've shown $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \sin \theta$$ Can you explain me how do you get the former one?

Comment: I will edit my answer in order to answer your question, that is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to consider $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}=F$, and then apply the following formula $$ 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \sin \theta
$$

Answer (score 2):

Start from
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \sin \theta $$
You replace $f$ everywhere with $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x'}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}\cos \theta + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} \sin \theta $$
Now plug in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$ on the right side

Comment: You've said _You replace $f$ everywhere with $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$_. Would you mind saying its reason?

Comment: The second derivative is the derivative of the first derivative. So in the formula for the first derivative I just replace the function with the first derivative